# Foliation of the tangent bundle of $n$-sphere

Tags: smooth-manifolds, vector-bundles, foliations

Is there a smooth $n$-dimensional foliation of $TS^{n}$,( here $n\neq1,3,7$) such that the zero section be a leaf of this foliation?

Comment: Tangent bundle of the $2n$-sphere has no nontrivial subbundles because $TS^{2n}$ has nonzero Euler class, so it cannot be written as $P⊕Q$ where $P$ and $Q$ have positive rank, since these two bundles would have to be orientable and have zero Euler class.

Comment: This might(?) be relevant: http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2509719

Comment: @FrancoisZiegler thank you very much for the comment. at this time I do not access to link. Can you write me a short abstract of this paper?thanks

Comment: @AliTaghavi: the Math Review starts "The authors give a general criterion in cohomological terms for the existence of a 2-dimensional foliation on a given closed 4-manifold with a prescribed embedded closed surface as a compact leaf." The rest talks mainly about genus > 0, but maybe the article itself explains why...

Comment: @FrancoisZiegler thank you for your valuable comment.